# How the layoutPriority values work in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-simulator

I was experimenting with layoutPriority() modifier. First I set its value as 1. Then I set like below:

```
layoutPriority(0)
```

I have not observed any changes. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

You use `layoutPriority` when there is a race where you need to prefer some ui over  another like this one  [Hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-control-layout-priority-using-layoutpriority)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("This line will take more space than the one below.")
            Text("small short one.")
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

But after adding

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("This line will take more space than the one below.")
            Text("small short one.").layoutPriority(1)
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

Comment: I used:Text(" Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum Ioremipsum.")
              .padding(.vertical, 8)
              .layoutPriority(1)

Comment: And my confusion is: If I change the priority to 0, I observer no changes, no matter how large the amount of text is.

Comment: @MostafaShaminYeasar `layoutPriority` doesn't have to give a change except when there is a race

Comment: Got your point @Sh_khan. But I have a toggle switch element with the text view mentioned above. They are embedded in a GroupBox.